# Sonar Showing duplicated on Pojo Classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, sonarqube

First time i am using "Sonar Integrations" and sonar showing duplication on the lines however there seems to be no duplicacy in variables names and its @JsonProperty. For reference please find the attached image.

[image: Sonar error image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I sense that you have a question to ask, but currently this is just a statement of fact. You should [edit] your question to make it clearer just what information you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar also points out duplicated code in different files. Therefore you must have somewhere a different POJO in a different file, which also has getters for `id` / `order_id` / `user_id` / `item_id`.

But clicking on the orange bar next to your marked code, Sonar will show you with a tooltip that actually which other block is considered a duplicate of the marked one, and also in which file.

Comment: Thanks  @ytg.. just changed the order and it is not showing up now.And yeah it was present in other classes.

Comment: Sonar issues are not there as challenges to find workarounds for. You may get better results if you actually did something against the duplication. E.g. creating a parent class from which your classes can inherit their common methods.